# how to direct to another php page

Tags: php, html, sql, redirect

i want to direct user to another page after succesful login. below is my code. how to resolve this?

```html
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
 //$result = mysqli_multi_query($mysqli, $query);
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


$data= var_dump($data);
echo $data;

if($data != "NULL"){
 
  header("Location:home2.php");
}
else {
 echo "sorry" ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
$data= var_dump($data);
echo $data;
```

and you will be redirected.
If you echo anything before to use `header` this function does not work.

Comment: thank you.. it works. ive remove it and modify that piece of code if($data ){
 
  header("Location:home2.php");
}
else {
 echo "sorry" ;
}